# ERROR: No matching distribution found for blazingsql

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I was trying to pip install blazingsql. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blazingsql (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for blazingsql
```

I couldn't find anything on the forum.

I'm using Python 3.7. No virtual environment.

I also tried:

```
conda install -c blazingsql/label/cuda10.2 -c blazingsql -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge -c defaults blazingsql python=3.7
```

It didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: _I'm using Python 3.7. No virtual environment._ Are you not using Conda? If you are, have you tried creating a new environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pip package for BlazingSQL or the rest of the rapids eco system.

I just tried the exact same command `conda install -c blazingsql/label/cuda10.2 -c blazingsql -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge -c defaults blazingsql python=3.7` in a newly created conda environment and  had no issues. There is no currently prescribed way of doing this outside of a conda environment right now though people have figured out work arounds for different architectures like PowerPC.

Can you submit an issue on github (https://github.com/blazingdb/blazingsql/issues) and provide more information about the OS, driver version, and your cuda version?